# Finding c.d.f and p.d.f of Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

If X have a uniform dist. on the interval (0,1)

How do you find cdf and pdf of  $$Y = \frac{X}{1-X}$$

I know that pdf is

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1 &  0<x<1 \\
0 &  o.w \end{array} \right.$$

I do not know how to interpret  $\ \ Y = \frac{X}{1-X}$ and I know my interval changes when I use
$$\ \ Y = \frac{X}{1-X}$$ 
but it seems like when I plug $1$ it becomes undefined.

Comment: You should first write $\frac{x}{1-x} \leq y $ and solve for $x $. More help can be given from there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that 
$$
P(Y \le y) = P \left( \frac{X}{1-X} \le y \right) = P \left( X \le y(1-X) \right) = P(X(1+y) \le y ) = P\left( X \le \frac{y}{1+y} \right) 
$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: thanks I got answer using hint above!